# Unable to structure your api import.io

Tags: import.io

I want to extract some data from a URL through import.io, but when I publish my API it fails.

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Please put the text of the error message in your question.

Comment: As an aside, asking for help ASAP won't get you answers any sooner. Some may even choose not to answer when seeing that...

Answer (score 0):

Please report which URL you were trying to extract

You can also get in touch with support@import.io, they will try to help